# ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:while installing scikit-surprise on python 3.8

Tags: python, windows, installation, scikits

I am trying the following command on python 3.8 ,pycharm windows10 for installing the package scikit-surprise for the evaluation of the recommendations system:

```
pip install scikit-surprise
```

and getting the following error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
Collecting scikit-surprise
  Using cached scikit-surprise-1.1.0.tar.gz (6.4 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=0.11 in c:\users\ali\pycharmprojects\recommend\venv\lib\site-packages (from scikit-surprise) (0.14.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.11.2 in c:\users\ali\pycharmprojects\recommend\venv\lib\site-packages (from scikit-surprise) (1.18.2)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=1.0.0 in c:\users\ali\pycharmprojects\recommend\venv\lib\site-packages (from scikit-surprise) (1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10.0 in c:\users\ali\pycharmprojects\recommend\venv\lib\site-packages (from scikit-surprise) (1.14.0)
Installing collected packages: scikit-surprise
    Running setup.py install for scikit-surprise: started
    Running setup.py install for scikit-surprise: finished with status 'error'

    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\ALI\PycharmProjects\recommend\venv\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\ALI\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\scikit-surprise\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ALI\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\scikit-surprise\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\ALI\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-zf0pux8x\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\ALI\PycharmProjects\recommend\venv\include\site\python3.8\scikit-surprise'
         cwd: C:\Users\ALI\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\scikit-surprise\
    Complete output (51 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\surprise
    copying surprise\accuracy.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\surprise
    copying surprise\builtin_datasets.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\surprise
    copying surprise\dataset.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\surprise
    copying surprise\dump.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\surprise
    copying surprise\reader.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\surprise
    copying surprise\trainset.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\surprise
    copying surprise\utils.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\surprise
    copying surprise\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\surprise
    copying surprise\__main__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\surprise
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\surprise\model_selection
    copying surprise\model_selection\search.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\surprise\model_selection
    copying surprise\model_selection\split.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\surprise\model_selection
    copying surprise\model_selection\validation.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\surprise\model_selection
    copying surprise\model_selection\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\surprise\model_selection
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\surprise\prediction_algorithms
    copying surprise\prediction_algorithms\algo_base.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\surprise\prediction_algorithms
    copying surprise\prediction_algorithms\baseline_only.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\surprise\prediction_algorithms
    copying surprise\prediction_algorithms\knns.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\surprise\prediction_algorithms
    copying surprise\prediction_algorithms\predictions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\surprise\prediction_algorithms
    copying surprise\prediction_algorithms\random_pred.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\surprise\prediction_algorithms
    copying surprise\prediction_algorithms\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\surprise\prediction_algorithms
    running egg_info
    writing scikit_surprise.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to scikit_surprise.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing entry points to scikit_surprise.egg-info\entry_points.txt
    writing requirements to scikit_surprise.egg-info\requires.txt
    writing top-level names to scikit_surprise.egg-info\top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'scikit_surprise.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    writing manifest file 'scikit_surprise.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    copying surprise\similarities.c -> build\lib.win32-3.8\surprise
    copying surprise\similarities.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.8\surprise
    copying surprise\prediction_algorithms\co_clustering.c -> build\lib.win32-3.8\surprise\prediction_algorithms
    copying surprise\prediction_algorithms\matrix_factorization.c -> build\lib.win32-3.8\surprise\prediction_algorithms
    copying surprise\prediction_algorithms\optimize_baselines.c -> build\lib.win32-3.8\surprise\prediction_algorithms
    copying surprise\prediction_algorithms\slope_one.c -> build\lib.win32-3.8\surprise\prediction_algorithms
    copying surprise\prediction_algorithms\co_clustering.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.8\surprise\prediction_algorithms
    copying surprise\prediction_algorithms\matrix_factorization.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.8\surprise\prediction_algorithms
    copying surprise\prediction_algorithms\optimize_baselines.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.8\surprise\prediction_algorithms
    copying surprise\prediction_algorithms\slope_one.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.8\surprise\prediction_algorithms
    warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

    running build_ext
    building 'surprise.similarities' extension
    error: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v8.1\\lib'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\ALI\PycharmProjects\recommend\venv\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\ALI\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\scikit-surprise\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ALI\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\scikit-surprise\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\ALI\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-zf0pux8x\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\ALI\PycharmProjects\recommend\venv\include\site\python3.8\scikit-surprise' Check the logs for full command output.
```

how to solve this? I have tried to change the versions of python also changed the path variable but still the issue is not resolved.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf202003 scikit-surprise
```

Try this command for installing. It worked for me.